# Error Number: 1054 Unknow Column Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a code that retrieve data from table that link together. Here's the code

```
public function getdatamentor($key)
{
    $this->db->select('iduser');
    $this->db->where('idtraining', $key, false);
    $hasil= $this->db->get('ttraining');
    $this->getNama($hasil->result());
}

public function getNama($key)
{
    $this->db->select('nama');
    $this->db->where('iduser', $key, false);
    $hasil = $this->db->get('tmember');
    return $hasil;
}
```

But it return error

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'TWO00000' in 'where clause'

SELECT `iduser` FROM `ttraining` WHERE idtraining = TWO00000

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/gofastforex/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try by using  'TWO00000'

Comment: Remove `false` and try again. `$this->db->where('iduser', $key);`

Comment: @AfshanShujat; 'TWO00000' comes from $key parameter from controller

Answer (score 1):

Because use set `false` in where function third argument.

```
$this->db->where('idtraining', $key, false);
```

If you set false and value is string, where do not protect value (Lib can not auto add single quote) . And not protected, value will be treated as a field name. So you should be remove or set `true`.

```
$this->db->where('idtraining', $key);
```

Convert to SQL:

```
SELECT `iduser` FROM `ttraining` WHERE idtraining = TWO00000 # Before remove
SELECT `iduser` FROM `ttraining` WHERE idtraining = 'TWO00000' # After remove
                                                    ^        ^
                                       Lib added single quote to protected.
```

Comment: Because it is a `string`, needs the quotes.

Comment: @AhmadFaza Make sure the variable `$key` is not an array.

Comment: @CalosKao: $key = $this->uri->segment(3);
$isi['mentor'] = $this->model_training->getdatamentor($key);

Comment: You can use `var_dump($key)` to check value before execute query.

Answer (score 1):

Third param in `where` method is for escape

```
$this->db->where('idtraining', $key, true); //
```

Better to read here

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=where%20cla#CI_DB_query_builder::where

Answer (score 0):

Try Below

```
public function getNama($key)
{
    $this->db->select('nama');
    $this->db->where('iduser',"$key");
    $hasil = $this->db->get('tmember');
    return $hasil;
}
```